# Laravel Guzzle params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, guzzle

I have this curl request from the API docs

```
curl https://apidev.aaa.co.uk/api/v1/vouchers/2869512_1-9FDD --user TOKAN-HO:2eL4aKsSGCaN4FH8 -k
```

Now I'm trying to call this request with Laravel 5.1 using Guzzle library, so I do this

```
public function testacorne()
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $res = $client->get('https://apidev.aaa.co.uk/api/v1/vouchers/claimed', [
        'form_params' => [
            'user' => 'TOKAN-HO:2eL4aKsSGCaN4FH8'
        ]
    ]);

    dd($res);
}
```

This is what i get

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 107:
Client error: `GET https://apidev.aaa.co.uk/api/v1/vouchers/claimed` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
"Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

But the username and password are correct. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `--user` in this case is used for Basic Auth with cURL. Try sending authorization data not by form data, but in the same way as cURL.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('https://apidev.aaa.co.uk/api/v1/vouchers/claimed', [
    'auth' => [
        'TOKAN-HO', '2eL4aKsSGCaN4FH8'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: well but mostly of times is used the header Authorization, but if they are using another header, well this is ok